# I keep getting a syntax error for defining the variable with a list python

Tags: python

```
def load_papers(ballots_file_name, FirstFile):
    candidates = {}
    voter = 1
    with open(ballots_file_name, 'r') as j:
        for paper in j:
            paper = paper.split(',')
    for i in range(0, len(paper)):
        candidate_name = FirstFile
        [i]v_dict = {"voter": "voter", "pref": "int(paper[i])"}
    if candidate_name in candidates:
        candidates[candidate_name].append(v_dict[i])
    else:
        candidates[candidate_name] = [v_dict[i]]
        voter += 1
    return {"num_voters": voter, "candidates": candidates}
```

the error I get:

```
 [i]v_dict = {"voter": "voter", "pref": "int(paper[i])"}
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have a rogue newline in there.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message clearly states, the line `[i]v_dict = {"voter": "voter", "pref": "int(paper[i])"}` (more specifically, the `[i]v_dict` part) is not valid Python syntax. I assume you wanted `v_dict[i]` instead but that's a bit of a wild guess.

Also after a quick look at your code snippet there are quite a few things that are probably not going to work as expected, and possibly not going to work at all.

Comment: I want to delete this post can you pls remove your comment